# Terminal states gparted is already installed but I cant find it in my apps menu

Tags: gparted

when I tried to install gparted in the past using a command it worked without any problem.

But now when I tried to install the gparted in my newly installed Ubuntu with the same code it stats that gparted is already installed.

How is that even possible when I installed it for the first time.

Moreover there is no gparted in the apps menu ....

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gparted is already the newest version (0.25.0-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 454 not upgraded.
```

Comment: What is the output of `sudo -H gparted` ?

Comment: did you find it in  system>administrator ?? Also try rebooting.

Comment: which desktop are you using? I think gparted is part of the gnome desktop apps. try running it type `gparted` in a terminal. gparted is in a subdirectory of the apps menu.

Comment: sudo -H gparted      it says command not found

Comment: typing @gparted in terminal says that